# mysqldump and wamp

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

***Update:*** Finally got this thing working but still not sure what the problem was. I am using a wamp server that I access through a networked folder.

The problem that still exists is that to execute the mysqldump I have to access the php file from the actual machine that is being used to host the WAMP server.

***End of update***

I am running a wamp server and trying to use mysqldump to backup a mysql database I have. The following is the PHP code I am using to run mysqldump.

exec("mysqldump backup -u$user -p$pass > $sql_file");

When I run the script the page just loads inifnately and the backup is not created.

A blank file is being created so I know something is happening.

Extra info:

```
* exec() is not disabled
* PHP is not running in safe mode
```

Any ideas??

Win XP, WAMP, MYSQL 5.0.51b

Comment: I have tried to connect to the database using MYSQL Administrator (GUI Tools) and I am getting "MYSQL Error Number 2003 Cannot connect to MySQL server on localhost (10061)".

Does anyone know how to resolve this???

Answer (score 1):

mysqldump is likely to exceed the maximal time php is supposed to run on your system. Try using the command in cmd or increase the max_execution_time in your php.ini .

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure `$pass` is defined and doesn't have a space character at the start?

If it wasn't, `mysqldump` would be waiting for command line entry of the password.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen a while back. A co-worker pointed me to the MySQL GUI tools and I have been making backups with that. The Query Browser that comes with it is nice, too.

[MySQL GUI tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html)

Answer (score 0):

It might help to look at the stderr output from mysqldump:

```
$cmd = "mysqldump backup -u$user -p$pass 2>&1 > $sql_file";
exec($cmd, $output, $return);
if ($return != 0) { //0 is ok
    die('Error: ' . implode("\r\n", $output));
}
```

Also you should use [escapeshellarg()](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) if `$user` or `$pass` are user-supplied.

Comment: I have added this code to my script but I am still not getting any error information. The script never seems to end!!! I have used set_time_limit(30); before the script but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

I've also struggled with using the mysqldump utility.  I few things to check/try based on my experience:

- Is your server set up to allow programs to run programs with an exec command?  (My webhost's server won't let me.)  Test with a different command.
- Is the mysqldump utility installed?  Check with `whereis mysqldump`.
- Try adding the optimize argument `--opt`